# SwiftUI pop-out animation causes characters to shake on physical device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I'm attempting to do a simple pop-out animation with some text and an image in SwiftUI.  In the preview on the simulator it looks fine, but when using a physical device to preview or when building and running on a physical device the characters in the text of the animation shake and it looks awful.  Interestingly, the image moves fine.

I'm still new to SwiftUI so any advice or input would be very appreciated.

```swift
struct SplashScreenContent: View {

    @State private var blurRadius: CGFloat = 10
    @State private var movingShadowX: CGFloat = 4
    @State private var movingShadowY: CGFloat = 4
    @State private var imageSize: CGFloat = 50
    @State private var fontSize: CGFloat = 55
    @State private var bottomInset: CGFloat = -5
    @State private var trailingInset: CGFloat = -3

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Animate", action: buttonPress)
            Spacer()
            VStack(spacing: 45) {
                Image(systemName: "house")
                    .resizable()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 1.5)
                    .shadow(color: .yellow, radius: 5)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 3, x: movingShadowX, y: movingShadowY)
                Text("I'm so\nShakey")
                    .font(.custom("NewYork-regular", size: fontSize))
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.bottom, 70.0)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 1.5)
                    .shadow(color: .yellow, radius: 5)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 3, x: movingShadowX, y: movingShadowY)
            }
            .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: bottomInset, trailing: trailingInset))
            .blur(radius: blurRadius)
            .onAppear(perform: animate)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

extension SplashScreenContent {

    func buttonPress() {
        blurRadius = 10
        movingShadowX = 4
        movingShadowY = 4
        imageSize = 50
        fontSize = 55
        bottomInset = -5
        trailingInset = -3
        animate()
    }

    func animate() {
        withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.4).delay(0.8)) {
            blurRadius = 0
            withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 4).delay(0.3)) {
                movingShadowX = 6
                movingShadowY = 9.5
                imageSize = 53
                fontSize = 58
                bottomInset = 13
                trailingInset = 3
                withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5).delay(4.3)) {
                    blurRadius = 20
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image: The image is fine, but the text is so shakey]

I tried removing the shadows, changing how much everything was animating, and so on.  The text remains to be shakey.

Comment: Tested on iPhone 14 pro device, seems ok, `. shadow` wasn't defined so used `.black` and also tested with `.blue`. There is no shaking for me. Could you test on a different device or try rebooting your device and testing

Comment: @user1046037 Thank you for taking a look.  I'm running an iPhone 13 Pro Max.  I've tried rebooting with no luck.  Unfortunately, I do not have another device I can test on.

Comment: Also, sorry for the `.shadow` color, that was a color I added.  In this case, it's just `.black`.  I'll update the example to use that instead.

Comment: Oops mine is iPhone 12 Pro (got confused with iOS version). Push it to TestFlight and ask your friends to test it, anyway TestFlight needs to be done at some point.